# trying to run powershell script silently failing

Tags: powershell

I've never seen this one, and a search didn't find this issue.  A script that ran last week this way with output is silently failing this week.  I checked the file has read/wright/run checked in windows explorer.  I tried set-executionpolicy remotesigned at the PS prompt.

This script is run at the windows command prompt like this:

powershell "powershell.exe {c:\temp\crashAfter.ps1}"
(no results)

The other ways I've tried are:
powershell
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
.\crashAfter.ps1
(no results)

I've also tried:
PowerShell -File c:\temp\crashAfter.ps1
(no results both at powershell prompt and at just regular windows command line)

What could cause powershell to fail silently like this? It works to go to the powershell prompt at the command line.

This is the script, which hasn't changed since last time I ran it:

```
 $today=[system.datetime](Get-Date)
 $startTime=$today.AddHours(-4)
 $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='Application Error';Data='SearchUI.exe';StartTime=$($startTime);EndTime=$($today);} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 foreach ($event in $events)
 {
   $crashOccurredTime=$event.TimeCreated
   $lookForInitStart = $event.TimeCreated.AddMinutes(-2)
   $eventInit = {Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='Application Error';StartTime=$lookForInitStart;EndTime=$crashOccurredTime;} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object -PipelineVariable Message -Match 'SearchUI'
                }
   if($eventInit -ne $null)
   {
     Write-Host "Found SearchUI.exe after SearchUI TimeCreated $($event.TimeCreated) ProviderName $($event.ProviderName) Message $($event.Message)"
   }
   else
   { 
     Write-Host "none"
   }
 }
```

Last Friday when I ran this script, it was using our application that we can use to run scripts, and my results looked like this (not sure what CLIXML is):

```
#< CLIXML
Found SearchUI.exe after SearchUI TimeCreated 08/08/2022 13:46:45 ProviderName Application Error Message
...
```

Comment: `PowerShell -File c:\temp\crashAfter.ps1 ` is the right way to invoke your script. Is the script _failing_ or does the `Get-WinEvent` call simply not find matching entries? CLIXML is PowerShell's XML-based object-serialization format, which normally doesn't surface on the command line.

Comment: @mklement0 - you are correct.  It just wasn't finding any events meeting the criteria, and that tails case didn't print anything.  It worked to just run a script that printed hello, and I figured out that I didn't find any events.

Comment: At the command line it was giving no outout when I ran it. When run thru our scheduling program, it gave a weird xml line. It's possible that the tails case was receiving a default character/true/false, and that was causing the CLIXML to print weird stuff out, or maybe it was our running program printing that out